# Getting SUM for each unique fields in Django Query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following table relations.

[image]

I want SUM of total_cost from Sales_Transaction for each party_name from the Party table. The Parties have 1:M relation with Sales and Sales has 1:M relation with Sales_Transction.

I tried this query but it returns the sum for all parties:

```
Party.objects.aggregate(sales=Sum('sales__salestransaction__total_cost'))
```

This is similar to this simple query:

```
SalesTransaction.objects.aggregate(sales=Sum('total_cost'))
```

I want output like this:

```
| Party Name | Total Purchase |
-----------------------------
|Party 1     | total_cost (calculated form Sales Transaction)
|Party 2     | total_cost (calculated form Sales Transaction)
```

**How can I achieve these results in Django Query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the `Party` objects with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Party.objects.annotate(
    sales=Sum('sales__salestransaction__total_cost')
)
```

The `Party` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `sales` with the total amount of sales for that `Party`.

Comment: It is working but not with follwing queryset code:    qs = qs.filter(party_name__icontains=self.request.GET['q']).annotate(total_sales=Sum('sales__salestransaction__total_cost'))